# Sorting buttons Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, ransack

I am using Rails 4 with Ransack to build simple search and sorting functionality.
My intention is to use POST request instead of GET (because of limitations).

So I would have 4 buttons. One click on button sorts ASC, then second click sorts DESC. It is pretty much the same as http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack?view=asciicast first example.

So far I have like this.

Controller:

```
  @search = Advertisement.search(params[:q])
  @ads = @search.result
  @search.sorts = ['height asc','age asc','price asc','votes asc'] if @search.sorts.empty?
      respond_with(@advertisements)
```

In view :

```
  Sort:
  <%= f.sort_fields do |s| %>
    <%= s.sort_select %>
  <% end %>
```

It looks like this :

[image]

Instead of selecting  each time ASC or DESC in collection I want to do it with one button.

I searched on google similair questions but no one was exact like mine.
Is there posibility to do so ? To use POST request not GET to sort with Ransack?

Or I have to switch back to GET request based sorting with limitations for user?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't already used ransack before, but this is the way that I would be to go:

1. **Create** a master sort button, in normal html, something like this:

```html
<select id="master_sort">
  <option class="asc">ASC</option>
  <option class="desc">DESC</option>
</select>
```

2. "**Bind**" the action of your select code with jQuery. When the user change that value, it will change all the sub-sort button in cascade (with a simple jquery function)
3. **Hide** the default sort selects with CSS.